# jQuery Masonry - items not correctly organized

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

After changing format of my existing report, I have noticed that after filtering one of the items, masonry is not correctly fired.  Example below:

http://relevantcodes.com/Tools/ReportUnit/res.html

Notice that "Filter Fixtures -> Passed" fails to work correctly yet all other filters work.  When "Passed" is selected for "Filter Fixtures", the items are arranged vertically instead of in the predefined grid.  All other filters work correctly, that is, they are rearranged both horizontally and vertically.

I've tried everything but nothing seems to work and its a really weird issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the masonry documentation:

```
1. If set to an Element or Selector String, Masonry will use the width of that element.
2. If columnWidth is not set, Masonry will use the outer width of the first element.
```

I just inserted a sizing item within the masonry container like so, and it works.

```
<div class='container masonry'>
    <div class='sizer'>..</div>
    <div class='item'>..</div>
    <div class='item'>..</div>
</div>

.sizer { width: 49%; } // default
```

And my responsive code has other widths that I am using to set the size.

Comment: Glad it worked out; this is actually the underlying reasoning behind my answer, but it turned out to be much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of javascript, and the display renders very nice, but there is one major thing that I can almost guarantee is your problem. It's a little much code for me to replicate and verify, but I would strongly suggest the following:

Your masonry approach uses a show/hide filter which is animated in itself. The challenge this poses is that masonry makes its calculations on where to put things immediately, but show/hide have animations that take a moment to finish. What you're left with is a luck-based approach to masonry knowing what the resulting display is going to be. Here are a few options I would consider:

1. Switch from masonry to isotope. It's the same underlying engine, but it has built in filtering that removes this complication from the problem entirely.
2. Delay your masonry adjustment until after show/hide completes (I believe it's .5 seconds by default).
3. Use a placeholder div for each item. This one is a fun one, but the idea is that you put a container around your elements that will show/hide that takes a placeholder for the width/height of the element. You attach the placeholder div to masonry, so that way as you show/hide your inner element, masonry still understands what it should be. Its invisible to the user, so it doesn't have a noticeable difference.

Anyway, long story short, I think #1 is the best approach. It would have saved you a significant amount of time in development to use it for filtering. #2 is kind of a hack that may at least allow you to test to see if the issue is related to what my answer. #3 is handy information if you ever have a grid that has elements that change size as the user interacts with them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: As a side comment, completely unrelated to your question but maybe some helpful information is that you may want to consider avoiding using "return;". One is that it's not valid javascript (you could do return false;), but I would especially avoid scenarios where you are using it to escape a function. Again, not criticizing, but it would be worth considering using if/else rather than if/return.

Comment: Thank you Lawrence.  #1 is out of question due to the licensing for isotope.  I tried #2, but it didn't work. I will try #3 as you've mentioned.  What's strange is all other filters work perfectly well, except this one.  Also, thanks for pointing the mistakes with return statement, I have fixed them all.

Comment: BTW, an isotope license is only $25 for a commercial license, free for personal use under GPLv3. Seems pretty reasonable.